# LibVLCSharp Media Player stops when app is minimized

Tags: c#, uwp, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I have a `UWP Application`. I am using a `LibVLCSharp.Uno.VideoView` and `LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer`. I have a problem, when the app is minimized the player stops. I added a `Background Media Playback Capability` [image: Capabilities]

The code, how I initialize a `LibVlc, MediaPlayer, and Media` [image: Initialization]

The `MainPage.xaml` code[image: MainPage.xaml]

[Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_PwUgYau0VpCse-CDI382ZyAB-maeu6X/view?usp=sharing) When I start playing, minimized application and unminimized.

03.01.2024
I resolved my problem by adding the below code to initialization MediaPlayer

```
var backgroundSystemMediaTransportControls = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls;
backgroundSystemMediaTransportControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
backgroundSystemMediaTransportControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
```

Comment: don't post pictures of code, post code

Comment: check what is freed upon going to background